# How to pass multiple values in a single go to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, user-input, exe

I have a script (.bat) file which needs 5 values from user input. These inputs are string format: Login ID, Environment, FileName1, FileName2, Region.
I am asking user to input it via set /p command but wanted to pass all values at go using command line.

For Eg: **test.bat value1, value2, value3, value4, value5**

These values should be catched individually inside batch.

I tried storing it to a text file and then reading from it. Though this helps in catching values not actually this is not the requirement.

Have a look at below sample code:

```
@echo off

< para.txt (
set /p Login_id=
set /p environment=
set /p Archive=
set /p import=
set /p region=
)

echo %Login_id%
echo %environment%
echo %Archive%
echo %import%
echo %region%

pause >nul
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can handle input parameters in a batchfile as in follows sample:

```
set Login_id=%1
set environment=%2
set Archive=%3
set import=%4
set region=%5
```

Comment: In general, yes - but the syntax `set "Login_id=%~1"` is preferred because that way parameters which contain spaces may be assigned by "quoting the parameter" (where the `~` removes the enclosing quotes) and thequotes in the command ensure any spare and remarkably-invisible trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned to the variable. That last potential problem can be a nightmare to solve the first time you encounter it...